# OrmLite not throwing exception on refresh with no result

Tags: javadoc, dao, ormlite, sqlexception

The Javadoc for the Dao refresh() in method states:

> Throws:
>   SQLException - on any SQL problems or if the data item is not found in the table or if more than 1 item is found with data's id.

However the class *com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.MappedRefresh* has another Javadoc definition and returns a result code all the way back up to refresh and to the user.

```
/**
 * Execute our refresh query statement and then update all of the fields in data with the fields from the result.
 * 
 * @return 1 if we found the object in the table by id or 0 if not.
 */
public int executeRefresh(DatabaseConnection databaseConnection, T data, ObjectCache objectCache)
        throws SQLException {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ID id = (ID) idField.extractJavaFieldValue(data);
    // we don't care about the cache here
    T result = super.execute(databaseConnection, id, null);
    if (result == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    // copy each field from the result into the passed in object
    for (FieldType fieldType : resultsFieldTypes) {
        if (fieldType != idField) {
            fieldType.assignField(data, fieldType.extractJavaFieldValue(result), false, objectCache);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Is this a bug or just a Javadoc mistake for Dao.refresh?

I'm looking at OrmLite 4.41.

Answer (score 0):

The internal methods usually have less than perfect Javadocs given that it is only for developers.  Also, I tend to not document every exception thrown.

In this case, the `MappedRefresh.executeRefresh(...)` method docs look pretty good except for the fact that it isn't documenting the exception.  If you look at the `super.execute(...)` line which calls `MappedQueryForId.execute(...)`, you can see that it has the following test/throw:

```
} else if (result == DatabaseConnection.MORE_THAN_ONE) {
    logger.error("{} using '{}' and {} args, got >1 results", label, statement,
        args.length);
    logArgs(args);
    throw new SQLException(label + " got more than 1 result: " + statement);
}
```

`fieldType.assignField(...)` and other methods can also throw `SQLException` on various data or database problems.

So the `Dao.refresh(...)` javadocs are correct.  The `MappedRefresh.executeRefresh(...)` javadocs are also correct but are missing details about the exception.